# La place d'un pronom COD par rapport à son antécédent

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, conjugaison

Mon titre n'est pas trop clair, mais, par exemple, pour autant que je sache, les deux phrases suivantes sont correctes:

1. J'ai vu les enfants jouer.
2. Je les ai vus jouer.

Mais ce que je ne comprends pas c'est la place de « les enfants » par rapport à « les », qui y fait référence. Je sais que sans « jouer », on met le pronom COD avant le verbe duquel il dépend, donc « je les ai vus » est correct. Cependant, pourquoi est-ce que l'on change quand il devient un pronom COD (« les ») d'un nom (« les enfants ») dans le context ci-dessus ? J'imagine qu'il manque quelque chose d'évident dans ma compréhension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La place de « les enfants » n'est pas figée dans :

> J'ai vu les enfants jouer.

On peut aussi écrire :

> J'ai vu jouer les enfants.

En revanche, il n'y a pas ce choix avec le pronom qui doit se placer avant le groupe verbal avec les verbes de perception, comme voir :

> [Je] [**les**] [ai vu jouer].

cf. [Parlez-vous French](https://parlez-vous-french.com/la-place-des-pronoms-complements/#:%7E:text=En%20effet%2C%20les%20pronoms%20se,du%20verbe%20%E2%80%9Cdonner%E2%80%9D.)

> Si le groupe infinitif est composé d’un verbe de perception comme regarder, entendre, voir, écouter, sentir, etc, le pronom se place devant tout le groupe infinitif. En effet, dans ce cas le verbe à l’infinitif est dépendant du verbe conjugué.

Comment: Voilà merci ! C'est exactement ce que je cherchais.

Answer (score 3):

*D'après [Gymlish](https://www.gymglish.com/fr/frantastique-orthographe/grammaire-francaise/la-place-des-pronoms-cod-coi-me-te-lui-leur)*

> Les pronoms COD/COI (me, te, lui, leur...) se placent :
> •  avant le verbe
> •  avant l’auxiliaire être ou avoir
> •  avant l’infinitif
> Je **te** connais bien ; Je ne **lui** plais pas.
> Tu **les** as vus hier ? ; Tu ne **leur** as pas demandé d’argent ?
> Je peux **vous** aider ? ; Je vous prie de ne pas **me** déranger.

« Complément d'objet direct d'un nom » n'est pas une fonction ; un complément d'objet direct est toujours le complément d'objet direct d'un *verbe*.

Comment: Merci - mais dans mon exemple, pourquoi est-il « je les ai vus jouer » au lieu de « j'ai vu les jouer » ? Autrement dit, je ne comprends pas la raison pour laquel  « jouer » ne modifie pas « les », parce que si c'était le cas, on aurait mis le « les » devant « jouer », non?

Comment: @DerekAllums I see, you have got the idea, somehow, that "les" should be in the second sentence at the same place where you find "les enfants" in the first? Right?

Comment: Basically, yes. In fact I know that it is *not* the case, but what I was looking for is the exact rule which explains this.